# Dynamically add data into Rows and column using userform VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I newbie in VBA-Excel.
I have problem to how insert data as dynamic from userform into sheets or table, output what I want is when commandbutton in userform on click then value insert as dynamically based name of participant. here my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim BarisSel As Long
Sheets("db").Activate
lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 2

Cells(lRow, 1) = cb_class.Text
Cells(lRow, 2) = cb_room.Text
Cells(lRow, 3) = tb_name.Text

'insert caption for Training Filed and every Question
Cells(lRow, 4) = trainingField.Caption
Cells(lRow, 5) = Qustion_1.Caption
Cells(lRow, 5) = Qustion_2.Caption
Cells(lRow, 5) = Qustion_3.Caption
Cells(lRow, 5) = Qustion_4.Caption

'Answer Question number 1 using OptionButton
If Jwb_1_A Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "A"
If Jwb_1_B Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "B"
If Jwb_1_C Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "C"
'Remarks for Answer B or C using text box
If Jwb_1_B.Value = True Then Cells(lRow, 7) = Tb_1_B.Text
If Jwb_1_C.Value = True Then Cells(lRow, 7) = Tb_1_C.Text


'Answer Question number 2 using OptionButton
If Jwb_2_A Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "A"
If Jwb_2_B Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "B"
If Jwb_2_C Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "C"
'Remarks for Answer B or C using text box
If Jwb_2_B.Value = True Then Cells(lRow, 7) = Tb_2_B.Text
If Jwb_2_C.Value = True Then Cells(lRow, 7) = Tb_2_C.Text


'Answer Question number 3 using OptionButton
If Jwb_3_A Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "A"
If Jwb_3_B Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "B"
If Jwb_3_C Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "C"
'Remarks for Answer B or C using text box
If Jwb_3_B.Value = True Then Cells(lRow, 7) = Tb_3_B.Text
If Jwb_3_C.Value = True Then Cells(lRow, 7) = Tb_3_C.Text


'Answer Question number 4 using OptionButton
If Jwb_4_A Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "A"
If Jwb_4_B Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "B"
If Jwb_4_C Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "C"
'Remarks for Answer B or C using text box
If Jwb_4_B.Value = True Then Cells(lRow, 7) = Tb_4_B.Text
If Jwb_4_C.Value = True Then Cells(lRow, 7) = Tb_4_C.Text

....
....
....
....
....

'Until Question end
End Sub
```

The output is not what i want, is just overwrite when i change next name participant. This is screenshot in excel for output what I want:

#### Output I would like:

[image: Output what i want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code puts everything in one row. You must add 1 to lRow every time you want to insert something in a new row, e.g.:

```
'insert caption for Training Field and every Question
Range(Cells(lRow, 4), Cells(lRow + 3, 4)) = trainingField.Caption
Cells(lRow, 5) = Qustion_1.Caption
Cells(lRow + 1, 5) = Qustion_2.Caption
Cells(lRow + 2, 5) = Qustion_3.Caption
Cells(lRow + 3, 5) = Qustion_4.Caption

'Answer Question number 1 using OptionButton
If Jwb_1_A Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "A"
If Jwb_1_B Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "B"
If Jwb_1_C Then Cells(lRow, 6) = "C"
'Remarks for Answer B or C using text box
If Jwb_1_B.Value = True Then Cells(lRow, 7) = Tb_1_B.Text
If Jwb_1_C.Value = True Then Cells(lRow, 7) = Tb_1_C.Text


'Answer Question number 2 using OptionButton
If Jwb_2_A Then Cells(lRow + 1, 6) = "A"
If Jwb_2_B Then Cells(lRow + 1, 6) = "B"
If Jwb_2_C Then Cells(lRow + 1, 6) = "C"
'Remarks for Answer B or C using text box
If Jwb_2_B.Value = True Then Cells(lRow + 1, 7) = Tb_2_B.Text
If Jwb_2_C.Value = True Then Cells(lRow + 1, 7) = Tb_2_C.Text
...
```

Comment: Hallo, Egan Wolf. That's it, my problem has done. Thank's for your answer..... it appear just add a little code.... Thanks a lot Egan. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231226(v=vs.60).aspx) to find where your code deviates from the expected behaviour?

If you are unfamiliar; you can set a breakpoint by clicking in the margin next to your code.

[image]

Execution will halt when the breakpoint is reached.

[image]

You can then execute your code one line at a time, by pressing F8.  This is great way to debug VBA, as you can see what each line is doing.  While debugging you can hover over variables, and a tooltip will show you the current value.

[image]

If you resize the VBA and Excel windows, so both are visible, you will be able to see the output as it is generated.  I suspect you will find the code that updates lRow is not functioning as you had expected.

Comment: Hai destination-data, thanks for your answer. I often using immediate window and pressing F8 to know one by one my code is running. Thanks for tell me to using breakpoints to find code, is't good advice... :-)